# Problems with breaking for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, break

I am currently having a problem with R not following my break command.

Here are my two inputs:

1. Elements should not be bigger than 16, but it is returning two elements bigger than 16:

   ```
   for (ndx in calc:length(b)) {
     print(calc) 
     if(calc >16) {break}
   ```
2. For this one, I should not be getting elements in my loop that are >50 and <6, but am getting them anyways:

   ```
   for(ndx in a){
     print (a^2)
     if (a>50 && a<6) {next}}
   ```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible, you need to insert the definitions of `calc, b` and `a`. Also, I formatted and indented it for you, but there's a missing close-brace on the first snippet.

Comment: And when you say 'returning', I assume you mean 'printing' or 'outputting'

Comment: As to outputting unwanted elements, note you do an unconditional `print` first, then you test the condition. Surely you should test the condition first, before printing?

Comment: So calc, b and a all have elements already! By returning I did mean printing, thank you!

Comment: So my conditions should come in first?

Comment: **We need to see the actual definitions of `calc, b, a`** otherwise we can't run or debug your code. Simply having definitions is not enough, we need to see the values. Are they unsorted lists of integers? vectors of strings? lists-of-named-lists-of-floats?? etc.

Comment: "a"<- 1:10

"b" <-seq(1,10, 2)

Comment: 'calc' <-((b)*3)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, replacing the variables with more generic names (I'm assuming that `calc` is an integer, otherwise the `:` operator shouldn't work anyway)

```
for (i in j:k) {
   print(j) 
   if (j>16) break
}
```

Note that *the value of `j` is not changing during the loop* (the index variable `i` is never used in the loop, and no variables get modified in the loop, so *nothing* changes due to the loop body except for the index variable). So if `j>16` it will be printed exactly once (provided `length(j:k)` is at least 1). Otherwise the loop will never break and `j` will be printed `length(j:k)` times.

Maybe

```
for (i in j:k) {
   print(i) 
   if (i>16) break
}
```

is what you had in mind??

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do.  As written, it doesn't do anything other than print `j` some number of times (as my answer explains). You might need to edit your question to explain in more detail what you want the code to do and what you think it's doing ...

Answer (score 0):

You do an unconditional `print` first, then you test the condition. Surely you should test the condition first, before printing?